# How can I audit with the Microsoft SQL Server LDF file?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, audit, audit-trail

We need an audit log in the product that we are creating. We use SQL Server 2008 R2. I learned that the LDF file keeps an complete log of all transactions that where made*.

I've found ApexSQL Log, this tools analyses the LDF file and provides a GUI. It's a great demonstration of what's possible. But it's expensive. More info: http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Do you know of other programs that can analyse the LDF file's? Or perhaps other methods to provide audit-trail functionality? I know that it's possible to create triggers. But if it isn't necessary to add things to my database scheme then I would rather not do it.

*Only if you select the full recovery model.

Answer (score 0):

How about the new Change Data Capture (CDC) functionality in R2. Doesnt that serve your purpose ?

Comment: This could be a very nice option but unfortunately you need a enterprise edition for this option (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx) We would like to offer our customers the possibility to start with the SQL Server express edition.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the information stored in an LDF file, make sure to form a full log chain. A log chain is a continuous sequence of transaction log backups. It starts with a full database backup followed by all subsequent log backups up through the auditing point. If it becomes broken, only the transactions in the logs up to the last backup before the missing one can be shown with full information (e.g. a schema and object name, or a row history)

Unlike INSERT and DELETE operations, which are fully logged in the LDF files, UPDATE operations are logged minimally – only the changes that are made are logged, but the old and new values are not. When logging UPDATE operations, SQL Server doesn’t log complete before and after row states but only the incremental change that occurred to the row. For example, if a word “log” was updated to word “blog” SQL Server will, in general case, only log an addition of letter “b” at index 0. This is enough for its purpose of ensuring ACID but not enough to easily show before and after states of the row. So, in order to understand what changed really occurred, you have to reconstruct the context in which the change occurred from the rest of transaction log and/or backup and online database data